# Learning F# Through Game Dev chapter 3 error

Tags: f#

I am going through the Learning F# Through Game Development book and in chapter 3 I am getting a TypeInitializationException with the following code:

```
// edit: missing definitions, thanks John
let earth_mass  = 5.97e24<kg> // defined in other file that is ref'd in ok
let moon_mass = 7.35e22<kg>

let lerp (x:float<'T>) (y:float<'T>) (a:float) = (x * a) + (y * (1.0 - a))
// inside list comprehension for loop -
let m = (lerp earth_mass moon_mass (rand.NextDouble())) * 1.0e-4 // error!!
```

I've downloaded the authors source to see if I missed something but it yields the same error.
The exception message gives little clue to what the issue is either (to me at least).

Here is the whole code for this chapter for reference:

```
namespace Games

module Chapter3 =
open System
open System.Threading
open Games.Math

type Asteroid =
    {
    Position : Vector2<m>
    Velocity : Vector2<m/s>
    Mass     : float<kg>
    Name     : string
    }

let dt = 60.0<s>
let G = 6.67e-11<m^3 * kg^-1 * s^-2>

let earth_radius = 6.37e6<m>
let field_size = earth_radius * 60.0
let max_velocity = 2.3e4<m/s>
let earth_mass  = 5.97e24<kg>
let moon_mass = 7.35e22<kg>

let create_field num_asteroids =
    let lerp (x:float<'T>) (y:float<'T>) (a:float) = x * a + y * (1.0 - a)
    let rand = Random()
    [
    for i = 1 to num_asteroids do
        let m = (lerp earth_mass moon_mass (rand.NextDouble())) * 1.0e-4
        let x = lerp 0.0<m> field_size (rand.NextDouble())
        let y = lerp 0.0<m> field_size (rand.NextDouble())
        let vx = max_velocity * (rand.NextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0) * 0.1
        let vy = max_velocity * (rand.NextDouble() * 2.0 - 1.0) * 0.1

        yield
            {
            Position = { X = x; Y = y}
            Velocity = { X = vx; Y = vy}
            Mass = m
            Name = "a"
            }
    ]

let f0 = create_field 20

let clamp (p:Vector2<_>, v:Vector2<_>) = 
    let p,v =
        if p.X < 0.0<_> then
            {p with X = 0.0<_>}, {v with X = -v.X}
        else
            p,v
    let p,v =
        if p.X > field_size then
            {p with X = field_size}, {v with X = -v.X}
        else
            p,v
    let p,v =
        if p.Y < 0.0<_> then
            {p with Y = 0.0<_>}, {v with Y = -v.Y}
        else
            p,v
    let p,v =
        if p.Y > field_size then
            {p with Y = field_size}, {v with Y = -v.Y}
        else
            p,v
    p,v

let force (a:Asteroid, a':Asteroid) =
    let dir = a'.Position - a.Position
    let dist = dir.Length + 1.0<m>
    G * a.Mass * a'.Mass * dir/(dist * dist * dist)

let simulation_step (asteroids:Asteroid list) =
    [
        for a in asteroids do
            let forces =
                [
                    for a' in asteroids do
                        if a' <> a then
                            yield force(a, a')
                ]    
            let F = List.sum forces
            let p', v' = clamp(a.Position, a.Velocity)
            yield
                {
                    a with
                        Position = p' + dt * v'
                        Velocity = v' + dt * F/a.Mass
                }
    ]

let print_scene (asteroids:Asteroid list) =
    do Console.Clear()
    for i = 0 to 79 do
        Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 0)
        Console.Write("*")
        Console.SetCursorPosition(i, 23)
        Console.Write("*")
    for j = 0 to 23 do
        Console.SetCursorPosition(0, j)
        Console.Write("*")
        Console.SetCursorPosition(79, j)
        Console.Write("*")
    let set_cursor_on_body b =
        Console.SetCursorPosition(
            ((b.Position.X/4.0e8<m>) * 78.0 + 1.0) |> int,
            ((b.Position.Y/4.0e8<m>) * 23.0 + 1.0) |> int)
    for a in asteroids do
        do set_cursor_on_body a
        do Console.Write(a.Name)
    do Thread.Sleep(100)

let simulation() =
    let rec simulation m =
        do print_scene m
        let m' = simulation_step m
        do simulation m'
    do simulation f0
```

Code for Math module:

```
namespace Games

module Math =
[<Measure>]
type m //metres

[<Measure>]
type kg //kilogram

[<Measure>]
type s // seconds

[<Measure>]
type N = kg*m/s^2 //Newtons

type Vector2<[<Measure>]'T> =
    {
        X : float<'T>
        Y : float<'T>
    }

    static member Zero : Vector2<'T> =
        { X = 0.0<_>; Y = 0.0<_> }

    static member (+) (v1:Vector2<'T>, v2:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        { X = v1.X + v2.X; Y = v1.Y + v2.Y }

    static member (+) (v:Vector2<'T>, k:float<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        { X = v.X + k; Y = v.Y + k }

    static member (+) (k:float<'T>, v:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<'T> = v + k

    static member (~-) (v:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        { X = -v.X; Y = -v.Y }

    static member (-) (v1:Vector2<'T>, v2:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        v1 + (-v2)

    static member (-) (v:Vector2<'T>, k:float<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        v + (-k)

    static member (-) (k:float<'T>, v:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<'T> =
        k + (-v)

    static member (*) (v1:Vector2<'a>, v2:Vector2<'b>) : Vector2<'a * 'b> =
        { X = v1.X * v2.X; Y = v1.Y * v2.Y }

    static member (*) (v:Vector2<'a>, f:float<'b>) : Vector2<'a * 'b> =
        { X = v.X * f; Y = v.Y * f }

    static member (*) (f:float<'b>, v:Vector2<'a>) : Vector2<'b * 'a> =
        { X = f * v.X; Y = f * v.Y }

    static member (/) (v:Vector2<'a>, f:float<'b>) : Vector2<'a / 'b> =
        v * (1.0/f)

    member this.Length : float<'a> =
        sqrt((this.X * this.X + this.Y * this.Y))

    static member Distance(v1:Vector2<'T>, v2:Vector2<'T>) =
        (v1 - v2).Length

    static member Normalize(v:Vector2<'T>) : Vector2<1> = 
        v / v.Length
```

Code to run example:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    Games.Chapter3.simulation()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Could someone please explain what is going on, using VS2013 and F# 3.1/.Net4.5

thank you.

Mick

Comment: Supplying the missing definitions, the code runs fine for me (using fsi in linux).  Maybe the error is from somewhere else?

Comment: Using your updated definitions still produces no error.  Please provide a simple code sample that can be cut and pasted and run that produces an error

Comment: Thanks John, I updated my post to include the definitions (is that what you meant?).there is a reference to the other file that holds the 'Measure' definitions. This has been working ok for the previous chapters so I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: I'll edit the main post now, thanks John

Comment: How is the code organized? All code in 1 script? Code in multiple scripts `#load`ed? Multiple files as part of a console app? Some code in a library, referenced by a console app?  I just tried putting the Math module in a library and referencing it from console app containing the rest of the code, and the compiler completely died.

Comment: All code is in a simple console app, the 3 code segment samples above are in separate files set up in the project in the following order:
Math.fs
Chapter3.fs
Program.fs

Comment: I compiled and ran the whole thing succesfully on Mono using 3 script files.  It produced some `a`s that wandered around the screen.  Can you reproduce the same error with less code?

Comment: Putting everything in 1 console app works ok for me in VS 2013, both in debug and release builds. If you could provide a ZIP of a repro solution that might help. Maybe your machine is in some bad state?
There is definitely some compiler issue when splitting into app + library though: https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/362

Comment: Thanks John, that's what is supposed to happen so that's good.

Comment: latkin, I've create a git repo https://github.com/MickDuprez/Learning-Fsharp-Through-Game-Development-chapter-3 . I've tried rebooting, rebuilding and creating new solution et al but same result. It will be something simple, it nearly always is :)

Comment: Ok I repro the problem now on a different machine, and I think I understand the problem. Will provide proper answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It believe you are running into [this](http://visualfsharp.codeplex.com/workitem/61) F# compiler bug.  It's present in F# 3.1.2 and earlier, but has since been fixed, so in 4.0 and later this will work.

Per the issue discussion, in F# 3.0 and earlier the bug existed, but didn't always cause a runtime crash. Looking at the book's sample code project, I'm guessing the author wrote these samples using F# 3.0 or earlier, and did not realize they were triggering the bug.

Workarounds:

- Compile in Release mode (with optimizations ON), and codegen should be correct (assuming this is really the same issue)
- Try using an F# 4.0 pre-release (either via [VS 2015 CTPs](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-ctp-vs.aspx) or grab just the F# bits from [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/releases))

Comment: Great work latkin! A thorough explanation and the work around did the trick and yes, the compiler bug does seem to be a similar issue if not the same. I normally code in C# and VS is rock solid, F# being a new thing I just wanted to make sure it wasn't me... Thanks for your efforts, I can sleep now :) Thanks John for taking the time to look, cheers.